# Unidirectional Many-To-One:saving parent entity generates unwanted insert into child table

Tags: jpa, many-to-one, composite-primary-key

I need to use a @JoinColumn @ManyToOne column as part of a composite primary key (having preferred option for defining composite key @IdClass, not @EmbeddedId).

The enities involved are Parent and Child - relation sort of similar to employee and department, with the only difference that I only need to access child ('department') fields from parent ('employee'), never vice versa. Therefore I use unidirectional @ManyToOne in the Parent entity.

Currently I have an issue with updating the parent table - upon parent entity update, hibernate tries to insert a record into the child table and understandably fails with primary key violation. I need to suppress the inserts to child table. I hoped that 'insertable = false, updatable = false' in the annotation would solve the issue, but it doesn't.

I used these guides to set up a composite primary key: https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-composite-primary-keys, https://dwuysan.wordpress.com/2012/02/22/joincolumn-is-part-of-the-composite-primary-keys/ , https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-composite-primary-key-with-jpa-and-hibernate/

My code comes below.
Parent entity:

```
@Data
@Builder
@Entity
@Table(name = "Parent", schema = "dbo")
@IdClass(value = ParentPrimaryKey.class)
public class Parent {


    @Id
    @Column(name = "dateTime", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Timestamp dateTime;

    @Id
    @MapsId("child")
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "child", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Child child;

    @Column(name = "status")
    private Integer status;

}
```

Parent's primary key entity:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class ParentPrimaryKey implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1;

    private Timestamp dateTime;
    private String child;

}
```

Child entity:

```
@Data
@Entity(name = "Child")
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "Child", schema = "dbo")
public class Location implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "child")
    private String child;
    @Column(name = "param")
    private String param;
    // some other child param fields

}
```

Integration testing on in-memory H2 with some entries to TestTable available:

```
    @Test
    public void shouldSaveRecord() {
        Parent selectedRecord = parentRepository.findAll().get(0);
        selectedRecord.setStatus(9);
        parentRepository.save(selectedRecord);
    }
```

Logs generated by running the test:

```
2019-07-01 09:52:20.547 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL - select parent0_.dateTime as dateTime1_15_, parent0_.child as child 3_15_, parent0_.status as status4_15_ from dbo.Parent parent0_
2019-07-01 09:52:20.555 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL - select child0_.child as child1_5_0_, child0_.param as param3_5_0_ from dbo.Child child0_ where child0_.child=?
2019-07-01 09:52:20.602 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL - select parent0_.dateTime as dateTime1_15_0_, parent0_.child as child3_15_0_, parent0_.status as status4_15_0_ from dbo.Parent parent0_ where parent0_.dateTime=? and parent0_.child=?
2019-07-01 09:52:20.630 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL - insert into dbo.child (child, param) values (?, ?)
2019-07-01 09:52:20.636 [main] WARN  o.h.e.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - SQL Error: 23505, SQLState: 23505
2019-07-01 09:52:20.636 [main] ERROR o.h.e.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - Unique index or primary key violation: "PRIMARY_KEY_81 ON DBO.CHILD(CHILD) VALUES ('MTS_0102_010R4', 8)"; SQL statement:
insert into dbo.child (child, param) values (?, ?) [23505-197]

org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint ["PRIMARY_KEY_81 ON DBO.CHILD(CHILD) VALUES ('MTS_0102_010R4', 8)"; SQL statement:
insert into dbo.child (child, param) values (?, ?) [23505-197]]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
```

I need to suppress unwanted insert into child table.
Any help would be highly appreciated.

Upd 2019-07-02. Current solution: had to switch to @EmbeddedId. Sort of pain, as I had to update all non-native queries. Still wondering whether it could have been managed with @IdClass.